# How to center multiple floated divs with fixed size

Tags: css, html, center, multiline

I want the child divs to be always centered within their container, even on resize, and without changing their size.

Problem Example : http://jsfiddle.net/bQMj7/

HTML

```
<div id='foo'><div id="container" class='group'>
    <div class='childs'>one</div>
    <div class='childs'>two</div>
    <div class='childs'>three</div>
    <div class='childs'>four</div>
    <div class='childs'>five</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#foo {
       text-align:center;
    }

#container {
    background-color:beige;
    display:inline-block;
}

.childs {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.group:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

I used the "inline-block / text-align:center" technique to center the child divs in their main container. When you resize the window, the floated child divs collapse, that's what I want, BUT as they collapse they're not centered anymore within their container.

I want the cloud of these collapsing-on-resize divs, to be always centered.

Do you have any idea?

**Edit** : Thanks for the reply, that's pretty much what I'm looking for ! My concern however is that:

- The reason why I used float left instead of inline-block is that I wanted those child divs to have no space between each others (which they do have as line elements unless I mess up my code indents to have those many childs on the same line code)
- I want the collapsing final line to be aligned left just as the other lines, but the whole being centered.

Here's an update with the two issues above : http://jsfiddle.net/bQMj7/6/.

Answer (score 1):

you may use `inline-block` for all of them and fake a `float : center ;` **wich doesn't exist**.

```
#container{
    background-color:beige;
    display:inline-block;

}
#foo{
    text-align:center;

}

.childs {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px;
}
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/bQMj7/1/

Comment: Thank you ! Please check the edit, I added some explanations of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/collabcoders/bQMj7/3/

```
#container{
    background-color:beige;
    display:inline-block;
}
#foo{
    text-align:center; 
}
.childs {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.group:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

**EDIT:** If I understand you correctly you want the space gone between blocks but still keep the center.   inline-block for some reason put 4px space on the right so simply add `margin-right: -4px;` to fix:

HERE'S THE NEW FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/collabcoders/bQMj7/10/

and the update to the .child class

```
.childs {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Please check the edit, I added some explanations of what I'm looking for.